# Trouble in sorting ObservableCollection in WinRT

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, observablecollection

I need to sort a list view containing meetings as per starttime in xaml winRT .
I am binding the meetinglist to UI .
We can't use sort descriptions in WinRT so I am trying to sort the ObservableCollection of my meeting model.
Here is my code:

myMeetings.xaml :

```
<ListView x:Name="myMeetingsList"    
                ItemsSource="{Binding SortedData}"....
```

myMeetings.xaml.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<T> SortedData
    {
        get {return _sortedData; }
        protected set {Sort();}
    }

    public void Sort() {
        _sortedData = new ObservableCollection<T>(_myMeetings.OrderBy(a=>a.startTime));
    }
```

When I try to display the sorted meeting list.It doesn't show anything.
I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions ??

Comment: How do you set the view's data context?

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish that the property `SortedItems` has changed. You'll need to raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event. Otherwise, the engine doesn't know you've changed the list to a new instance.

Or, copy the newly sorted items into a freshly cleared instance of `_sortedData`. Just don't create a whole new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you wish SortDescriptions were part of the WinRT CollectionViewSource?  Oh, man, I do. Same thing with filters and groups. But, no need for that talk; it is what it is.

Sorting an ObservableCollection is just like sorting anything else only you need to be sure not to reset the value of the collection only its members. Like this:

```
var o = new ObservableCollection<int>();

// fill collection ascending
var n = Enumerable.Range(1, 50);
foreach (var item in n)
    o.Add(item);

n = n.Reverse();
// fill collection descending
o.Clear();
foreach (var item in n)
    o.Add(item);
```

Do you have to do all this in code-behind? Practically speaking, yes. You could monkey an attached property or something but it's just more code for something that's pretty simple.

Because you call `Clear()` and not set `o` to a `new ObservableCollection<int>()` again, the UI will keep up with your changes just fine. So no need for additional events or whatever.

The question remaining is when the sort should be called. This will be on a case-by-case basis. And, only you know your app. When the X data is changed, call your Sort().

Having said that, if you think that the value of X will change frequently, then you might want to throttle the event using Reactive Extensions. If it's not frequent then never mind that part.

**How to sort an observable collection?**

If you look at the solutions out there that do this. They are just doing what I am doing in the code above. They just subclass Observable Collection. Is all that worth something so simple? Maybe. You can decide that. But it's all doing the same thing. My recommendation, less is more.

Best of luck!